# how to manage div in one line sort-able using j-query

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I am creating div Sortable() using j-query. I am getting refer of http://jqueryui.com/sortable/. but here div is vertical line. But I want all div in one line. so I have created but when I drag div then designing or sequence is disturb. I cant drag with disturb design. Please help. Thanks in Advanced.

Answer (score 0):

> To arrange sortable items as a grid, give them identical dimensions and float them using CSS.

Demo: http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#display-grid
click on "view source" to see the code